# C# - How to set the working directory for a batch file from C# code?

Tags: c#, batch-file, directory

```
CSGOHammer.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\runtime\hammer.bat";
CSGOHammer.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @InstallPath + @"\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\bin\hammer.exe";
CSGOHammer.Start();
```

I'm trying to set the working directory for this .bat file, but this code doesn't seem to work. Any help?

EDIT: Problem fixed! The workingdirectory was set to \bin\hammer.exe instead of \bin so now everything is working as it should work!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: the working directory of the .bat file is not actually set, even though i tried to set it to the working directory

Comment: Did you debug and check what value is in InstallPath ?

Comment: Yes I did. It's the correct path.